# error Path must be a string without null bytes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express

I want to upload an image form Angular on front-end to MongoDB. I managed to send the photo to the back-end side but getting this error when I use **fs.readFileSync**.

**HTML Component**

```
<input #fileInput type="file" />
<button (click)="addFile()">Add</button>
```

**TS Component**

```
 addFile(): void {
  let fi = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
   if (fi.files && fi.files[0]) {
   let fileToUpload = fi.files[0];
    this.usersService
    .upload(fileToUpload, this.id)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
 }
```

**Service**

```
upload(fileToUpload: any, id: string) {
    let input = new FormData();
    input.append("file", fileToUpload);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/profile/photo/' + id,input);
 }
```

**Node.JS**

```
router.post('/photo/:id', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.files);
User.find({ _id: req.params.id })
    .exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occured',
                error: err
            });
        }
        user.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files.file.data);
        user.img.contentType = 'image/png';
        user.save((err, obj) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err
            }
            console.log('success')
        })
    });
});
```

**Mongoose Model**

```
const schema = new Schema({
  img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

**Console.log(req.files)**

```
>{file:
> { name: '2017-11-30 11_45_17-500px Blog » The passionate photographer community.50 Creative Self-Portrait Ide.png',
>   data: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 02 de 00 00 03 84 08 06 00 00 00 96 f6 36 7a 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 00 04 ... >,
>   encoding: '7bit',
>   mimetype: 'image/png',
>   mv: [Function: mv] } }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cant you simply do  user.img.data = req.files.file.data; ? As the content of the image appears to be in memory, you dont need to read it from some path